# Aligning \mbox to right

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\mbox{ \parbox{8em}{\textbf {Registration Id:}}}  
\mbox{ \parbox{120pt}{\framebox(120,20)}}
\mbox{ \parbox{4em}{\textbf {Hall Id:}}}
\mbox{ \parbox{50pt}{\framebox(50,20){}}}
```

I want to shift 3rd and 4th \mbox to left.
If I use \hfill, it shifts out of the right bounds and enter the right margin.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you show where you have placed the `\hfill` commands and complete the code snippet to a minimal document with `\documentclass` etc.

Comment: why do you have the `\mbox` at all? they  are doing nothing other than add the space character after `{ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `\mbox` and `\parbox` are supposed to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{Registration Id:} \framebox(120,20){}\hfill
\textbf{Hall Id:} \framebox(50,20){}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following picture also shows the type block margins as heavy rules:

[image]